# OpenAPI Client Generator combine multiple files and projects

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using the OpenAPI generator(https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to generate a C# client.

I get two C# projects(OpenAPITools and OpenAPITools.Test) -

[image]

Right now with the command below, a .sln and two projects are created -

```
-jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -i 
libmaster_limited.yml -g csharp -o client_generated
```

1. Is there a way so that only a single project is created containing the content of both the current projects?
2. I have multiple Open API specs and I want them all to be under one single solution(each spec can have it's own project). Is that possible?

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new if you've not done so.